# mysql command line show statements a sql script executes?

Tags: mysql, unix, command-line-interface

I'm a long time postgres user, but am now looking after maintenance for mysql databases. One thing that I'm used to from postgres, is when you run a sql script it will output on the command line what it is executing.. i.e.

```
cat myscript.sql | psql mydatabase
BEGIN;
INSERT;
COMMIT;
```

When I do a similar thing with mysql, I get no output and it will just churn away without giving me any status

```
cat myscript.sql | mysql mydatabase
```

Are there any flags I can use or something to the mysql binary so I can get an idea of whats going on when the script is executing?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the -v switch to turn on verbose mode which will display the commands as they are executed.

```
chris@eden:~$ mysql -v -uroot -p < mysqltest
Enter password:
--------------
show databases
--------------

Database
information_schema
mysql
--------------
show tables
--------------

Tables_in_mysql
columns_priv
db
event
.....
```